# Unable to solve error 'IMvxViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyChanged' )

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am facing this error:

> `IMvxViewModel` does not contain a definition for 
>       `PropertyChanged` and no extension method `PropertyChanged` accepting a 
>       first argument of type `IMvxViewModel` could be found (are you missing a 
>       using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my Code:

```
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(Position = MasterDetailPosition.Master, WrapInNavigationPage = false, NoHistory = true)]
public partial class MixedNavMasterDetailPage : MvxContentPage
{
    public MixedNavMasterDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        base.OnViewModelSet();

        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModel.SelectedMenu))
            {
                if (Parent is MasterDetailPage master)
                {

                    master.IsPresented = !master.IsPresented;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: That error is accurate according to the source code for that interface https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/MvvmCross/ViewModels/IMvxViewModel.cs

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to create MasterDetailPage with Multiple menus in MasterPage and it should open particular DetailPage when I click on that menu. I am unable to do this. please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That error is accurate according to the source code for that interface

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/MvvmCross/ViewModels/IMvxViewModel.cs

If however you have created a custom view model that extends the default provided by the framework and derives from `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then you would need to first check and then cast the view model to the desired type before being able to used the desired members,

```
protected override void OnViewModelSet() {
    base.OnViewModelSet();
    var viewModel = ViewModel as INotifyPropertyChanged;
    if(viewModel != null) {
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
            if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedMenu") {
                if (Parent is MasterDetailPage master) {    
                    master.IsPresented = !master.IsPresented;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented above code but now it is showing error on SelectedMenu

Comment: @Diksha same issue. what is the type of view model? You would need to cast it to the desired type to be able to access it members. otherwise you will have to use raw string.

Comment: The type of ViewModel is IMvxViewModel.

Comment: What I am trying to do is like: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/Projects/Playground/Playground.Core/ViewModels/Navigation/MixedNavMasterDetailViewModel.cs